# How to draw a pipe being moved between tanks? (ISO standard P&ID)

Tags: pipelines, standards, pistons, pi-diagram

Where I work, we have a set-up that functionally, works as represented below:

[image]

I represented it as such, due to a lack of know-how in regards to the actual, ISO-standardized way of representing this kind of set-up. There are two tanks being switched every 8 hours, meaning that I can't just represent one valve as normally-open and the other as normally-closed. Thus, I had to label the valves (which is wrong in it of itself, since they aren't actually labeled), and then I simply had to describe their usage, with the "A xor B" line.

Lastly, the switching between tanks isn't even done through valves. It is done through a pneumatic piston that physically moves a cut-off pipe from one tank to the other. I have no idea how to represent a pipe being moved by a piston on command from the control center.

So, how do I represent this set-up in accordance with ISO standards?

**EDIT:**

In discussion with Forward Ed, I was shown how I could make a piston symbol, and simply write the action happening. The exact arrangement however, I did myself. I am a bit unsure if what I did is in accordance with ISO standards, and if it is a clear and logical way to represent it. So, as a sub-question to this question, is this representation acceptable?

The rectangle with the "T" in it, is the symbol Forward Ed created. The line with the dotted circle is supposed to represent a mechanical connection, as the moving rod on the piston is connected to the pipe. I got this from this site. As for the dotted line, that's supposed to represent the alternative discharge. There's an issue with this though. I've been taught that striped lines are meant for signalling between instruments and the control center (though not between the instrument and the measured quantity). The linked-to site seems to agree with this, calling striped lines electric signals (though that seems like a more general label).

[image]

In this drawing, I used a dotted line however, which to me, is visible different from the striped lines. However, that might not be the case for everybody, which could cause confusion, given that I use striped lines to represent communiation between instruments and the control center. And then there's of course the issue of whether a dotted line representing an alternative line is in accordance with ISO standards to begin with. Lastly, writing the action might AFAIK not be in accordance either.

Comment: Just trying to understand this in my own words.  There is actually only one valve.  it is closed every 8 hour while the discharge pipe is moved from one tank to the other?

Comment: I am not sure about ISO standards, but if my understanding above is correct I would put the valve on the vertical line.  I would make a solid line discharge to one tank.  I would make a dashed discharge line to the other tank.  I would point a leader at the dashed discharge pipe and annotate it with something like "Alternate discharge pipe location".  I would annotate the valve with something like.  Valve closed every 8 hours while discharge pipe is moved between tanks."

Comment: @ForwardEd There is only one valve, yes. It doesn't need to be closed during the relocation of the pipe though, as the tanks are physically close enough for spillage to be minimum. Some may opt to close the valve though, but that would be up to the individual operators.

Comment: @ForwardEd From what I've learned about ISO standards, dashed lines are used to represent instrument signals. Perhaps you have a different type of dashed line in mind?

Comment: In that case remove the note from the valve and just leave the valve on the vertical so as not to be affected by the positioning of the discharge pipe and change point a leader at the solid line and say something to the effect of "Discharge pipe alternates between tanks every 8 hours"

Comment: dashed, dotted, hidden, greyed line is shading is allowed.  Very thin line for alternate position and thicker line for the rest of the work.  Basically you are trying to show the alternate position while de-emphasizing it.

Comment: Wait, if dashed lines are only permitted for signals, how do you draw a hidden line?

Comment: @ForwardEd I have no idea how on could draw a hidden line, I've never had to. Though it would be practical to know. Also, in your set-up, there is no representation of the piston doing the relocation. Not sure if that's a problem as far as ISO standards are concerned, but I think it is? If it isn't, it would appear to me as some kind of exception to the general rule of complete detail. As for thinner lines, we've been taught that thick lines are used for the main process, and thinner lines are used for biproduct process lines and auxillary processes.

Comment: @ForwardEd https://www.edrawsoft.com/pid/images/pid-legend.pdf This legend seems to sugges you're correct, given that the dashed line is labelled a "straight line pipe", and the arrow-headed line is labelled "major straight line pipe". Furthermore, it makes no mention of lines representing instrument signals. However, I know for a fact what our teacher taught us. So, either the teacher was wrong, or this legend is wrong/incomplete.

Comment: the secondary tank is an auxiliary position.  Since this drawing looks to be more process or schematic in nature, I would assume there is some sort of std block for an hydraulic actuator.  I would place this on/over the pipe.  label it and state what it does.

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "std block", could you elaborate? Also, what do you mean when you're saying the drawing look more like process or schematic in nature? As opposed to what other natures? All I know is that it is supposed to be a P&ID (in chemical industry).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137140/discussion-between-forward-ed-and-user110391).

Comment: let me start by saying that I do not know much about what you are asking ... to me, what you are describing is one pipe, feeding one valve, feeding pneumatically operated diverter valve with two outputs

Comment: @jsotola Not a diverter valve. There is an open-ended, bendable discharge pipe, being pushed by a piston from one tank to another, or being pulled from the other tank back to the first. The liquid just pours out of the pipe into the tank. The actual valve on the pipe is far removed from the set-up, and is just used to shut off the stream whenever that is necessary. It isn't related to the switching function. The valves in the above drawing are imaginary.

Comment: it is still a device that switches between two outlets

Comment: @jsotola True, but does such a device count as a kind of valve? I thought there were stricter definitional restrictions on what counts as a valve.